Remove bottom edge on marplotlib bar plot
I need to generate a bar plot  but without the bottom edge. Here's an example output and code:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95])
y = np.array([0.0801 , 0.08062, 0.08136, 0.08728, 0.0836 , 0.08862, 0.09642,
              0.12204, 0.0722 , 0.20776])
plt.bar(x, y, width=0.1, alpha=0.5, align='center',
        fill=False, ls=':', lw=5, edgecolor='r')
plt.show()

I want to hide the bottom edge of the bars. Can this be done?

pyplot.bar (docs here) has a parameter called bottom, which sets the y-value the bars start to be drawn at - by default it's 0, as you'd expect. We can use this to adjust the bottom "edge" of our bars, and then set the ylim of your axis to effectively crop this out. One thing to notice here, however, is we then need to compensate for this in our y values, as these actually correspond to the height of the bars.
Your code can then become this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.array([0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95])
y = np.array([0.0801 , 0.08062, 0.08136, 0.08728, 0.0836 , 0.08862, 0.09642,
              0.12204, 0.0722 , 0.20776])

plt.bar(x, y+1, width=0.1, alpha=0.5, bottom=-1, align='center',
        fill=False, ls=':', lw=5, edgecolor='r')

# "crop" the bottom out
plt.gca().set_ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()

Noticing we set bottom=-1, mirrored with y+1 (which is actually height=y+1), and then set the ylim. This gives us the bars with no "bottom edge":


Instead of drawing the bars, you can simply draw the vertical and horizontal
lines of interest. You’ll need to incoporate some math/array operations, but
gain the added benefit of removing awkward overlapping lines which is
especially important for the dashed linestyle you are using.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95])
y = np.array([0.0801 , 0.08062, 0.08136, 0.08728, 0.0836 , 0.08862, 0.09642,
              0.12204, 0.0722 , 0.20776])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

width = .1
ly = np.array([y[0], *np.maximum(y[1:], y[:-1]), y[-1]])
lx = np.array([*x, x[-1] + width]) - (width / 2)

ax.vlines(lx, 0,       ly,     lw=5, ls=':', color='r', alpha=.5)
ax.hlines( y, lx[:-1], lx[1:], lw=5, ls=':', color='r', alpha=.5)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()


To work with a categorical x-axis, we simply need to convert
these data to numeric (using the same mechanics that matplotlib uses)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [*'abcdefghij']
y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 8]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True)

ax1.xaxis.update_units(x)
xlocs = ax1.xaxis.convert_units(x)
kwargs = dict(lw=5, ls=':', color='r', alpha=.5)

# top plot (ax1) width == 1
width = 1
left_x = xlocs - (width / 2) # remove (width / 2) to have left-aligned "bars"
right_x = left_x + width
ax1.vlines(
    x=   [*left_x, right_x[-1]],
    ymax=[y[0], *np.maximum(y[1:], y[:-1]), y[-1]],
    ymin=0,
    **kwargs
)
ax1.hlines(y, left_x, right_x, **kwargs)
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0)

# bottom plot (ax2), width < 1
width = .8
left_x = xlocs - (width / 2)
right_x = left_x + width
ax2.vlines(left_x,  0, y, **kwargs)
ax2.vlines(right_x, 0, y, **kwargs)
ax2.hlines(y, left_x, right_x, **kwargs)
ax2.set_ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()



Another interesting answer although I think the one by asongtoruin is still the easiest to implement for my particular needs. Thank you!

I like the clean vertical lines this gives, although it feels it would become more complicated if we were looking at a non-numeric x-axis.

Not terribly complicated, matplotlib converts strings to numbers for plotting anyways so we can just make use of its own mechanics to do this for us. See the example I added above.

You can loop over the bars, extract the outer path vertices, then replot the edge without the bottom vertice and finally mask the edge of the original bar:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95])
y = np.array([0.0801 , 0.08062, 0.08136, 0.08728, 0.0836 , 0.08862, 0.09642,
              0.12204, 0.0722 , 0.20776])
bars = plt.bar(x, y, width=0.1, alpha=0.5, align='center',
               fill=False, ls=':', lw=5, edgecolor='r')

for b in bars:
    # get path of the bar, remove bottom vertice
    x, y = b.get_path().vertices[1:].T
    # replot with original parameters
    plt.plot(x, y, alpha=b.get_alpha(), ls=b.get_linestyle(),
             color=b.get_edgecolor(), lw=b.get_linewidth(),
             transform=b.get_transform()
            )
    # hide original bar
    b.set_visible(False)

Output:

how it works:
b.get_path().vertices

array([[0., 0.],  # bottom left corner  <- we removed this one
       [1., 0.],  # bottom right corner
       [1., 1.],  # top right corner
       [0., 1.],  # top left corner
       [0., 0.]]) # back to top left

If you want to remove other edges, you can craft x/y accordingly, for instance to remove the top vertice:
x, y = [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]

Output:


Interesting approach but the answer by asongtoruin is easier to implement  so I'll select that one. Thank you!

@Gabriel yes, it's more hacky, but has the drawback of relying on the Y-axis limits ;)
